# Visual Studio Properties window for Unit Tests?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I found a blog entry that talks about the "Unit Test" property window, shown here:
[image]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/slange/WindowsLiveWriter/DataDrivenTestsinTeamSystemUsingExcelast_CF7E/image_thumb_3.png))</sub>

(Credit: image home is [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/slange/2009/09/03/data-driven-tests-in-team-system-using-excel-as-the-data-source/))

My question is that I can not for the life of me get a "Unit Test" to populate in the *Properties* window. I am running Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. When I click on a file in my *Solution Explorer* it shows up in the *Properties* window as expected. When I click anywhere in my code the *Properties* window goes blank.

I spent about 10 minutes Googling for an answer, but I was unable to find one (there was a lot of noise in the search results).

I'm sure that I'm missing something obvious here and I was just about to declare a loss when I figured I'd ask the good folks at SO if they had an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010, from the Test menu, select Windows\Test View

In the Test View window, you can then right-click the test and choose 'Properties'

(I can't find it in Visual Studio 2012 at all.)